# Texstudio change shortcuts for autocomplete dialogue

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion, shortcut

In the autocomplete dialogue that appears in texstudio when you begin to type a command it is possible to navigate through the autocomplete options using the up & down arrow keys.

[image: autocompletion]

Is it possible to reassign these actions to another key or key combination? Looking at the shortcut bindings, Down is only assigned to "Move cursor down" however, removing this shortcut does not change the behaviour of Down in the autocomplete dialogue.

Also, presuming it is possible to have an alternative shortcut, is it possible for this shortcut to be contextual - i.e. if I have Tab assigned to next placeholder, can I have it jump placeholders when the autocomplete dialogue is closed but when autocomplete is open, go to the autocomplete option below?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/614648/34551

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key binding for the completer is hard-coded. There is no way to change it.

Comment: Since this answer is a couple of years old now, I have taken the liberty to open an issue [on the bug tracker](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/1759) to see if a developer would be willing to alter this behavior.