# Change autocomplete key from `Enter` to `Tab` in texstudio

Tags: texstudio

I have been using texstudio for a few weeks. I really like the auto-predict feature in this when we type some arguments and the suggestions are displayed in a drop-down menu. However, I find it annoying that I have to press the `Enter` key to select suggestions as it is messing with my muscle memory to press the `Tab` key for completion. Is there any way to re-assign these keys in texstudio?
That is o use the`Tab` key for completing the prediction instead of `enter`
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [indicated in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/381051/34551), this shortcut is unfortunately hard-coded.

You can see [in the source code](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/blob/670624954907df24a49dacc17fee8527f8f33369/src/latexcompleter.cpp#L432) the `Qt::Key_Enter` that captures if the [enter key was pressed](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_catch_enter_key) "hard-coded" into the program.

I have [opened an issue](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/1759) to see if the developers would be willing to do anything about it.

Comment: Thanks for opening the issue.